# Moment.js add month is not working

Tags: momentjs

I want to add X months to a given date.I have used **add** for that.

> moment(date).add(2, 'm').format("DD/MM/YYYY");

By using like this months are not added.

Suggest correct way to add months.

Comment: try uppercase M for month, lowercase m is for minutes

Answer (score 8):

What about

`moment(date).add(2, 'month').format("DD/MM/YYYY");`

Comment: This has been now deprecated

Comment: @Omer would be nice if you included the version where it changed.

Answer (score 6):

```
moment().add('month', 1)
```

this will add 1 month.

```
moment(your_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add('month', 1)
```

this will add 1 month to your date with formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is now:

```
var timestring1 = "2013-05-09T00:00:00Z";
var timestring2 = "2013-05-09T02:00:00Z";
var startdate = moment(timestring1);
var expected_enddate = moment(timestring2);
var returned_endate = moment(startdate).add(2, 'hours');  // see the cloning?
returned_endate.isSame(expected_enddate)  // true
```

Comment: Are your sure you are answering the right question ?

Answer (score 1):

Veeram's comment works for me, but also make sure that the value of your date variable hasn't been previously formatted and that it matches known ISO 8601 formats.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
moment().add(moment.duration({ M: 1 })).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am using this in my project and this logic is working fine for me.**
$scope.o.DateOfBirth = "31/03/2021";

var currentDate =moment($scope.o.DateOfBirth, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var futureMonth = moment(currentDate ).add(24, 'month').format("YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(currentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
console.log(futureMonth.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));

**output : "2023-03-31"**